# How to avoid repeated commands while call last command?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

Normally, when i was using up button to get last commads on shell, my RPi was giving me the commands without showing repeated ones. Let say i command:
ifconfig
ifconfig
ps aux
ps aux
ifconfig
ifconfig
When i was using Up button to saw last commands:
ifconfig
ps aux
ifconfig

But now it makes:
ifconfig
ifconfig 
ps aux 
ps aux
ifconfig
ifconfig

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set or change the `HISTCONTROL` variable for your profile to include `ignoredups` or `erasedups` as you see fit. Short extracts from the bash documentation explains it better...

> A value of `ignoredups` causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved

---

> A value of `erasedups` causes all previous lines matching the current line to be removed from the history list before that line is saved

See the full [bash man pages](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bash/bash.1.en.html) and https://askubuntu.com/a/15929 for more details

Comment: These options (which I recommend) only affect typed commands - not recalling history